Android ValueAnimator onAnimationRepeat called during the animation execution
I'm using ValueAnimator to do something, but I'm confused with the time of onAnimationRepeat's invocation.
For this code:
valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 10);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        final int currentValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        if (lastAnimationValue == currentValue)
            return;

        Log.v("swifter", this + " onAnimationUpdate currentValue = " + currentValue);
    }
});
valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        Log.d("swifter", this + " onAnimationRepeat...");
    }
});

valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
valueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
valueAnimator.start();

I think the log output should be like this:
......
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 8
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 9
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 10
onAnimationRepeat...
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 0
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 1
......

But the real output is:
......
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 8
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 9
onAnimationRepeat...
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 10
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 0
onAnimationUpdate currentValue = 1
......

I always thought the timing of this method's invocation should be between two animations' execution.
Is this how ValueAnimator runs? if not, how to make it works like what I want?
